# Determine the largest set inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=inf ( x^2 , y^2 ) \in C^{1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Problem:** determine the largest set inside
$\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=\text{inf} ( x^2 , y^2 ) \in C^{1}$

i don't have idea for it.

Comment: Chekcing differentiability at the lines $x=\pm y$ would be helpful.